# Laravel Form ActionController form

Tags: php, forms, controller, laravel-5.1

Being new to Laravel, I do not quite understand how to add my input parameter in the form action controller as parameter. I have a page which has an input field (id = mapsearch).

When I put some value in mapsearch and hit enter my url should change from /reviews to /reviews/{mapsearch}

I have the controller in place, however when I add the variable in form controller it does not work.

> Route::get('/reviews/{mapsearch}','SearchController@resendReviews');

And the code for opening the form.

> ```
> {!! Form::open(array('action' => array('SearchController@postReviews', [$mapsearch]))) !!}
> ```

Please let me know what should be the value of parameter when the id of my input field is $mapsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever name you want in the parameter.
In the **resendReviews** method of the **SearchController** use the parameter as:-

```
function resendReviews($id)
{
    //The value of mapsearch will pass here.
    //U can name id whatever u want.
    echo $id;
}
```

Also if you are posting a form to a controller then you can access the posted data using..

```
function resendReviews($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    print_r($input);
}
```

But remember to use the following line when using Input.In the beginning a of Controller file add...

```
use Input;
```

Comment: It gives me an error when I enter any variable in form action parameter.

Comment: you need to be more specific about the error and also where you are stuck